# advisable to save username password in appDelegate iOS

Tags: ios, passwords, appdelegate

I dont want to save the login details in the keystore and have them persist.
 I want to save the username password while the app is being used and have the user login everytime he starts the app. (To make it secure).
I was planning to save the username_password in an object in the AppDelegate class and thus use the login credentials make web service calls across the app. Is this advisable? Or should I pass the username password across the controller objects?

I'm assuming the app delegate objects dies and all its variables will not be saved when the app is closed or killed.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: NANNAV: I dont want to save to NSUserDefaults. Because the value is persisted in NSUserDefaults. I am worried about security and since its not a requirement for the user to be logged in always I can save it in a non-persistent storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for security reasons, you must not store that information in NSUserDefaults (which is the best option for situations like that).

If you want to insert the username and password every time you enter the app you have two option:

1 - Create two variables in the AppDelegate
2 - Create a global class to store the information

Personally i recommend to create a global class.

For example: let's say your class is named "Global". In you .h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalValues : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *username;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *password;

@end
```

In your "Global" .m file you must create a instance, to have persistence of the information. Then you initialize that:

```
#import "GlobalValues.h"
#import "L0ViewController.h"

@implementation GlobalValues

@synthesize username;
@synthesize password;

GlobalValues *globalV = nil;

+ (GlobalValues *)getInstanceOfGlobalValues
{
    if (globalV == nil)
    {
        globalV = [[GlobalValues alloc] init];

        globalV.username = 0;
        globalV.password = 0;
    }

    return globalV;
}
```

To acess to information just call the method:

```
GlobalValues *global = [GlobalValues getInstanceOfGlobalValues];
NSString  *pass = global.password;
```

Regards

Comment: Miguel: Thank you! Why would I create a global class and not use AppDelegate. Is it for separation of logic?

Comment: @Jasmine Yes it's that.

Answer (score 1):

**First**: do you want to save only one password/user from the user? or do you want to save several passwords/users?

**Second**: What for is the server? Do you want to make a call to a web service to retrieve and save the password/user?

**Third**: Never, ever save password/user in NSUserDefault, for security reasons.

> **Keychain** IS the best way for saving passwords. If you want to use some persistence then you would need to use some hash to encrypt the password
>   value.

Check this tutorial for hash and keychain information:

[Basic Security in iOS part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475)

[Basic Security in iOS part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6603/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2)

Comment: Sophy: 1) Just one username/password 2) by server, I meant web services that I call to execute other app functionality. 3) Yes. thank you. I'm not saving the username/pass in NSUserDefaults.  I dont want persistence. hence can I save the username/pass in AppDelegate?

Comment: It is better that you separate classes. For example: save password should it be in "Save my PIN / Password" class. And in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application in AppDelegate call class "Load View Ask For My Password"

Answer (score 0):

You are correct unless you save them to some persistence like the NSUserDefaults or CoreData you will lose any variables that are set in the AppDelegate on each of the application starts.

Comment: Darren102: Thank you. I did notice that the app delegate persists if the app goes in background and then gets active again. It does not persists if I kill the app.

Comment: That is correct, when in the background it is just in a suspended state hence your data will persist unless the app is killed by low memory warnings.